# How to make the `static_assert` print the value it got on failure?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, static-assert

Running this:

```cpp
#define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)

template< int PathLength >
constexpr const int startfindlastslash(const char (&path)[PathLength]) {
    return PathLength;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    STATIC_ASSERT( startfindlastslash( "cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp" ) == 11 );
}
```

You got:

1. **`g++ -o main.exe --std=c++14 test_debugger.cpp`**

   ```
   test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
   test_debugger.cpp:1:28: error: static assertion failed: startfindlastslash( "cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp" ) == 11
    #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                               ^
   test_debugger.cpp:10:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘STATIC_ASSERT’
        STATIC_ASSERT( startfindlastslash( "cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp" ) == 11 );
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```
2. **`clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only --std=c++14 test_debugger.cpp > main.exe`**

   ```
   test_debugger.cpp:10:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'startfindlastslash("cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp") == 11' "startfindlastslash(
         \"cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp\" ) == 11"
       STATIC_ASSERT( startfindlastslash( "cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp" ) == 11 );
       ^              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:1:28: note: expanded from macro 'STATIC_ASSERT'
   #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                              ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~
   1 error generated.
   ```

The compiler does not tell which one was the value it was supposed to get, it only says the value is not equal.

Comment: I know the value it is printing in my example is fixed because I used a generic macro. But somehow could this macro could be fixed to show the actual value?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with `static_assert`. You could define a macro that would use a `template <int c> struct V {};` and try to make a copy of the struct and it would generate a compile time error if `c` value don't matches (something like cannot convert from `V<30>` to `V<11>`). The macro would need 2 parameters: expected and actual value and since it rely on compiler diagnostics, result might vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: @Phil1970, this seems awesome idea! Can you write an answer? (just sad they designed the standard **`static_assert`** with this problem)

Comment: I wrote such code maybe 15 years ago before `static_assert` was added to the language. I don't remember the exact implementation. In practice, `static_assert` works well enough and if you have a problem *guessing* the value, you can always debug the application by printing the actual value. Or use a unit test framework which usually would give both actual and expected values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often find it useful to wrap `static_asserts` in a function template. Then the compiler will print at least the function template parameters in the error message. If you combine this strategy with the value template approach of @Phil1970, you get pretty decent results.

When compiled with GCC, the following snippet prints the error message containing your values: `In instantiation of 'constexpr void assert_equal(const_val<T, A>, const_val<U, B>) [with T = int; T A = 30; U = int; U B = 11]'`

Clang is even better: `<source>:13:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement '30 == 11' "Values are not equal!"`.

```
#define MAKE_CONST(x) const_val<decltype(x), x>{}
#define STATIC_ASSERT_EQUAL(x, y) assert_equal(MAKE_CONST(x), MAKE_CONST(y));

template<typename T, T val>
struct const_val {
    constexpr const_val() = default;
    constexpr const_val(T v) {}
};

template<typename T, T A, typename U, U B>
constexpr void assert_equal(const_val<T, A>, const_val<U, B>) {
    static_assert(A == B, "Values are not equal!");
}

template< int PathLength >
constexpr const int startfindlastslash(const char (&path)[PathLength]) {
    return PathLength;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  STATIC_ASSERT_EQUAL(startfindlastslash( "cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp" ), 11);
}
```

It's not exactly the syntax you were using and it involves an additional macro for convenience, but hopefully it's sufficient for your purpose...

Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/aQSQev).

Answer (score 1):

[ This is not really an answer to "How to make static_assert print the value", but rather an explanation of why the OP is getting the behavior that he is. ]

Pre-c++17, `static_assert` takes two parameters.

The first is the expression to be evaluated, and the second is the message to be printed when the expression does not evaluate to true.

When you define your `STATIC_ASSERT` macro, you are giving `static_assert` the message that you want printed - and it is printing that message for you.